# Div inside a Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Im trying to access a div from my repeater by pressing a button which is in the repeater too
the div is in display: none; the button has a jquery script which comes in play OnClientClick.

heres a sample of the HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrPics" OnItemDataBound="rptrPics_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrPics_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="showDiv" OnClientClick="$('div[imageId=' + imageId + ']').slideToggle(); return false; />
<div runat="server" id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
SOME CODE
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

now the imageId is an Attribute which i set in the repeaterBinder

```
hiddenDiv.Attributes.Add("imageId", imgData.ProductId.ToString());
 showDiv.Attributes.Add("imageId", imgData.ProductId.ToString());
```

nothing seems to work need advices.

Comment: Do you really need server button here? Does it may fire postback or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function slideToggle(button) {
    $(button).next("div.hiddenDiv").slideToggle();
    return false;
}

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrPics">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="showDiv" OnClientClick="return slideToggle(this);" Text="Show" />
    <div runat="server" class="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;" >
        SOME CODE
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forget use this.getAttribute(name) in OnClick expression

```
OnClientClick="$('div[imageId=' + this.getAttribute(imageId) + ']').slideToggle(); return false; />
```